# How do I remove dependencies from my Ruby on Rails model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

I am a developer in C#, and know that this class is tightly coupled to both ActiveRecord and BCrypt. If I were using C#, I would extract the use of BCrypt into another class, and pass the new class in via dependency injection. As for the use of ActiveRecord, I would define a class that accepted this class as an argument to persist.

Should I be trying to take the same route with Ruby, or is there a better way to remove the dependencies on ActiveRecord and BCrypt?

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question is more directed towards coding style, but I would like to answer the question that may make all of this easier - and recommend that you check out the [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) method introduced in Rails 3.1. This will abstract out the `encrypt_password` and `authenticate` methods.

Now - on to your original question - you can use modules in Ruby to separate functionality. For your specific use case, a combination of `include` and `extend` are necessary, which I wrap up with an `included` hook.

```
module PasswordEncryption
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
        user
      else
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PasswordEncryption
end
```

Comment: From what I understand now, my main concern is that the BCrypt call will still be made when I'm running my unit tests. Won't my tests still be testing the BCrypt library?

Comment: Yes, they will. You could stub out the `BCrypt::Engine` methods, or, if speed is your concern, set `BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST` to `BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST` for your test environment. See [Rails Tutorial Listing 7.11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-test_bcrypt_cost_factor).

Answer (score 0):

To break the coupling for BCrypt then try creating a module and mixing it into your model class. There is a lot of information on the Web about Ruby mixins if you need it.

I'm afraid that breaking away from ActiveRecord might prove to be more difficult. You might consider using the same approach here by creating a module with you business logic, then mixing it into the AR class.

You can add callbacks to you modules which are called when they are included or extended, which is where you get your dependency injection. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included

### Response to comment about testing

Ruby makes it easy to just stub methods or include another module which would override the methods from your encryption module during testing. This seems a bit "dirty".

Let's say you have separated the encryption logic into a module called `Encryption::BCrypt`. You want to include that module except when running in the test environment. A clean way to do this is to create an initializer, e.g. config/initializers/encryption.rb, which has a line like this

`User.send(:include, Encryption::BCrypt) unless Rails.env.test?`

Then in your test code you would want to stub out the appropriate methods or include a test encryption module into your User class.

Comment: I responded in the answer above